# Webflux - hanging requests when using bounded elastic Scheduler

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have a service written with webflux that has high load (40 request per second)
and I'm encountering a really bad latency and performance issues with behaviours I can't explain: at some point during peaks, the service hangs in random locations as if it doesn't have any threads to handle the request.
The service does however have several calls to different service that aren't reactive - using `WebClient`, and another call to a main service that retrieves the main data through an sdk wrapped in `Mono.fromCallable(..).publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`.

So the flow is:

1. upon request such as `Mono<Request>`
2. convert to internal object `Mono<RequestAggregator>`
3. call GCP to get JWT token and then call some service to get data using `webclient`
4. call the main service using `Mono.fromCallable(MainService.getData(RequestAggregator)).publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`
5. call another service to get more data (same as 3)
6. call another service to get more data (same as 3)
7. do some manipulation with all the data and return a `Mono<Response>`

the webclient calls look something like that:

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> GoogleService.getToken(account, clientId)
                .buildIapRequest(REQUEST_URL))
                .map(httpRequest -> httpRequest.getHeaders().getAuthorization())
                .flatMap(authToken -> webClient.post()
                        .uri("/call/some/endpoint")
                        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authToken)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(countries))
                        .retrieve()
                        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
                            log.error("{} got status code: {}",
                                    ERROR_MSG_ERROR, clientResponse.statusCode());
                            return Mono.error(new SomeWebClientException(STATE_ABBREVIATIONS_ERROR));
                        })
                        .bodyToMono(SomeData.class));
```

sometimes step 6 hangs for more than 11 minutes, and this service does not have any issues. It's not reactive but responses take ~400ms

Another thing worth mentioning is that `MainService` is a heavy IO operation that might take 1 minute or more.

I feel like a lot of request hangs on `MainService` and theren't any threads left for the other operations, does that make sense? if so, how does one solve something like that?

Can someone suggest any reason for this issue? I'm all out of ideas

Comment: Rewrite `MainService` so that it does not block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to tell for sure without knowing the full application, but indeed the blocking IO operation is the most likely culprit.

`Schedulers.boundedElastic()`, as its name suggests, is bounded. By default the bound is "ten times the number of available CPU cores", so on a 2-core machine it would be 20. If you have more concurrent requests than the limit, the rest is put into a queue waiting for a free thread indefinitely. If you need more concurrency than that, you should consider setting up your own scheduler using `Scheduler.fromExecutor` with a higher limit.

Comment: i agree with @Martin Tarjanyi.  Use your own scheduler using threadpool executor and do a load test to tune the threadpool.

Comment: thank you and@Martin Tarjányi and @harry for the answeres. if decreasing the number of flatmap (by using map istead) would it help?

Comment: @LiorDerei I'm not sure how exactly you would use map instead of flatMap but that likely wouldn't make any positive difference.